# How to capture iPhone 6+ screenshots for iTunes connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

Apple requires that we submit iPhone 6 and 6 plus screenshots with apps that support those platforms.

My company owns iPhone 6s, but not 6 plus's (we're a small shop).

For devices where the simulator will fit on my Mac's screen, I can capture screen-shots of devices I don't have using the simulator. However, the iPhone 6 plus is too tall for that trick.

The app in question is a developer utility, and not likely to be a money-maker for us. We can't justify buying a 6 plus just to get these screen-shots.

How are other iOS developers satisfying this requirement?

Comment: Use `File` -> `Screenshot` in the simulator (or Command+S)? Is that not working for you? They get saved to the desktop by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use simulator print screen CMD+S it is simple.

*For iphone6S plus don't hesitate to scale with : window > scale > 50%.*

*It won't hurt your print screen but it will be easier than the huge simulator on the screen (like on my MBP 13 inch).*

All developers can't afford to buy all devices so it is the way to make print screen.

Comment: OMG, I completely forgot that there was a screen-shot command built into the simulator. Thank you. I feel like an idiot.